# ReactJs and Wordpress api is there a way to upload media

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

I am using ReactJs for my frontend and I am trying to upload a image to my backend which is Wordpress. Currently I am able to create post, pages, and do other things using the api. However when I try to upload a media file I get the following error.

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.
```

In my backend Wordpress api I have it set to allow the most command media types jpeg, jpg, png, etc. I can upload files from Wordpress direct but I am not sure what I am doing wrong that will not allow me to upload using Reactjs. I do have a JWt plugin and it is working correctly

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { UrlContext } from "../context/urlContext";

const UploadMedia = () => {
  const { url } = useContext(UrlContext);

  const imgUpload = useRef(null);
  const [img, setImg] = useState("");

  const updateItem = async () => {
    if (imgUpload.current.files.length > 0) {
      var formData = new FormData();
      let file = imgUpload.current.files[0];
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("title", file.name);
      formData.append("author", 1);
      formData.append("post", 1);

      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        url: `${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media`,
        data: {
          JWT: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci",
          formData,
        },
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "image/jpg",
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Disposition": "form-data; filename='" + file.name + "'",
        },
      };

      axios(options)
        .then(function (resp) {
          //   getItems(); //callback to parent's this.getItems(),
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };

  function previewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(imgUpload.current.files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
      setImg(oFREvent.target.result);
    };
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        if (img) {
          return <img src={img} alt="image" />;
        }
      })()}
      <input
        id="imgUpload"
        type="file"
        ref={imgUpload}
        onChange={previewImage}
      />
      <button onClick={updateItem}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadMedia;
```

When I console.log my options and headers this is what I get

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://api.elmc.app/wp-json/wp/v2/media",
  "data": {
    "JWT": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci",
    "formData": {}
  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "image/jpg",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; filename='400x400bb.jpg'"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you should try to console log your headers.  just referencing here.  Also, you are not trying to upload an SVG are you?

Comment: Im uploading .jpg and I tried .png

Comment: I updated the questions that show response from Axios and option